# Filter by id for multiple data in Django

Tags: python, django

```
id_tuple= (1,3,4,5,7,9)
students =Students.objects.filter(id in id_tuple)

for s in students :
s.name='_new_name_'
```

This code is giving error !
How can i solve it ??
based on the above tuple i want to get all student !

How to do that

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you want to filter students using IN, then this would do: `Students.objects.filter(id__in=id_tuple)`

Answer (score 18):

As stepnak stated to do an in query the correct syntax is `filter(id__in=id_tuple)`

Django documentation would have been a great resource to get this information. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: Works with an array too

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IN field lookup as @stepank suggests.

A little more explanation: Django ORM uses a special syntax to translate python code to SQL statements. And simply passing a `bool` (if `id` is defined) value to `filter` is not valid syntax.

If you are new to Django, you can get started from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/). You can also refer to the complete [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/). Referring to documentation before asking is a good practice. :)

Answer (score 1):

students =Students.objects.filter(id__in=id_tuple)